# Update query throws an error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, syntax-error

I have a delete function implemented on my website. A normal customer can delete his/her account and this updates a "delete" field from 0 to 1.
My table is called "users" and everything seem to work fine. However when I test the delete function I get the following error:

> " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'delete='1' WHERE email='active@user.com'' at line 1"

The code for my update query is shown below:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET delete='1' WHERE email='$email'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: avoid using MySQL [Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) by design, change all column names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DELETE` is a MySQL [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). If you're going to name a column after that you *must* wrap it in ticks;

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `delete`='1' WHERE email='$email'")or die(mysql_error());
```

You *really* shouldn't use `DELETE` as a column identifier. I strongly recommend changing it.

Comment: Yeh, I just realised it myself. I was about to post the solution. Thank you for your help.